# Started Node in safemode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm using CentOS for Hadoop implementation. When I start OS, by default hadoop will start in Safemode. After I remove it from "Safemode" and try to PUT data into HDFS, it pops 0 name nodes available. Some one told that "restart OS" would resolve the issue. Is there any way to get out of this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, forcing NN to come out of the safemode is not a very wise choice. During this period NameNode loads the file system state from the fsimage and the edits log file. Normally the time spent in safe mode is usually proportional to the size of the cluster or the size of your data.

In case you are not happy with the current configuration, you can use **dfs.safemode.threshold.pct** to change the NN safemode behavior. NN waits until a specific percentage of the blocks are present and accounted-for represented by this property. After this threshold is met, safemode is automatically exited. You can choose a smller value if you want your NN to come out of the safemode quickly.

Having said that, you can check a couple of things to make sure that  everything is running fine, if you are facing prolonged safemode :

- All data nodes are coming up properly.
- You have enough name node threads to be able to take care of the number of data nodes that want to check in. You can handle this by **dfs.namenode.handler.count**.

HTH